# Bridging issue while using AFNetworking with Pods in a Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I am facing problem when I initialise AFHTTPSessionManager in my swift class. I have added AFNetworking using pods in my project. It shows error use of undeclared type. But when I press CMD + Click on AFHTTPSessionManager it takes me to the right class.

[image: This is my bridging header class]

I have added bridging header and imported AFNetworking.h class in it. I have try to fix this issue by added bridging header in many ways.
1- I have created bridging header class myself by creating new header file
2- I have created objective c test class in swift project and added bridging header when it asks to add bridging header in project.

[image: This is how I set build settings]

[image: This is how I used AFNetworking in my Swift class]

Bridging header also didn't work with myself created test class when I tried to initialise it in my swift class.

Can anyone help me sorting out this issue?

Comment: Hi, I know this post is too old but I want just share my experience: I had exactly the same problem. I created files (swift files) before configure the bridge. After, I configured the bridge (file, building settings etc.). And NO, it never work. After long time and searches I try something stupid: I've deleted all files inside my projects that needs external library and I recreated these. Do you believe me when I says that after this stupid operation all things are working and I'm able to use AFNetworking that few minutes laters was "unresolvable"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know the pain... I ran into the same issues trying to get AFN working in a Playground. I was not successful in that endeavor. But it did work in the project and I learned a few things along the way.

First, I configure the bridging header in my Project's build settings (as you have done) and import AFN like this:

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

Second, I set the Pods Project build setting "Defines Module" to Yes.

[image]

Then I executed a plain build (Product -> Build or Option+B) to see if it took. Then I launched the Simulator.

Comment: Also, don't forget to "import" the newly created modules in your .swift file, like this: import AFNetworking   Note, that this is _not_ the bridging header, but the swift file

Comment: It was the "import" part that finally worked for me. I didn't expect that since AFN is in the bridging header...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work by [this](https://iosdevbits.blogspot.com/2014/12/finally-cocoapods-with-swift.html) link.

Then in the bridging header file, I imported the AFNetworking framework with as I would with any framework. I also imported BButton.h, which is a 3rd party library that's not a pod framework but something I placed directly into my project

```
#import "BButton.h"
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

Then in the Swift file that calls the AFNetworking code, I had to import AFNetworking but not BButton

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailButton: BButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Set the icon for the email signup button
        self.emailButton!.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("", comment: ""), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.emailButton!.setType(BButtonType.Primary)
        self.emailButton!.addAwesomeIcon(FAIcon.FAEnvelope, beforeTitle: true)


        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        manager.GET(
            "http://headers.jsontest.com",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
                responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
                error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        )

    }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Your external link is broken. It has some noise at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Beside all what you have done, Add "use_frameworks!" flag to your Podfile, to look like this :

```
target 'appName' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

run the "pod install" command again